# Download google spreadsheet use google spreadsheet api

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I have a working example that I got here. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ I need to download some files from user's google doc.

```
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MySpreadsheetIntegration {
public static void main(String[] args)
  throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {

SpreadsheetService service =
    new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

// TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)

// Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

// Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

// Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
  // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
  System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
}
}
```

Now I need to download some spreadsheets. How do I do it with google spreadsheet api?

Answer (score 1):

### Download spreadsheets

Use the google drive api to download spreadsheets. You can download as CSV, PDF etc.

Code sample: how to download with drive api - [Getting a merged cell width on Google Spreadsheet API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599412/getting-a-merged-cell-width-on-google-spreadsheet-api/15079447#15079447)

### Update with Spreadsheet-api (gdata)

To update the spreadsheet with data, use the Spreadsheet-api. See this google example http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn-history/r51/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java

### Update with google-apps-script

You can also use the more powerful google-apps-script to update a spreadsheet (server side java script).