# Determine the height of merged cells in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, spreadsheet

I am creating a spreadsheet that will sum the daily inserted hours per activity for each week individually. This spreadsheet allows an increase in height for each week as needed

(ex. week 3 in image below demonstrates another row for inserting a 3rd activity per day).

[image]

What I would like to do is find a way to determine the height of the merged cells on the left to be used in dynamically determining the cells to include in a sum total in the last column.

I have found [how to determine the existence of merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025543/how-do-i-know-if-spreadsheet-cells-are-merged-using-google-apps-script) and [how to determine the width of merged cells by exporting to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599412/getting-a-merged-cell-width-on-google-spreadsheet-api), but the latter seems it would not work for my situation as I am looking for a way to do instantaneous height determining to be used in an essentially fancy sum function.

I would like to know if/how it is possible to dynamically determine a merged cell's height using google apps script within google spreadsheet.

Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you know where the first row of where the merged cells is.  If you know the row position of the merged cell you want to change, I think you can use the `getRowHeight()` method of the Spreadsheet class, which returns an integer.

[getRowHeight Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRowHeight(Integer))

If the problem is, that you can't find the row position of the merged cell you want to change, that's a different question I guess.

You can also set the height:

[setRowHeight](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setRowHeight(Integer,Integer))

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // Sets the first row to a height of 200 pixels
 sheet.setRowHeight(1, 200);
```

Comment: Yes I know where the position of the first row of merged cells. This sounds like exactly what I need!